# Why 'l' and 'll' modifier do the same for printf (C)

Tags: c, printf, long-integer, libc

I don't understand the difference between `l` and `ll` length specifier for the printf function :

```
printf("%ld \n", 9999999991474836499);
printf("%lld \n", 9999999991474836499);
```

The two printf make the same output because to the type overflow:

```
-8446744082234715117                                                                                                                                                                                                              
-8446744082234715117
```

So when I remove one digit I do :

```
printf("%ld \n", 999999999147483649);
printf("%lld \n", 999999999147483649);
```

And I get the same output :

```
999999999147483649                                                                                                                                                                                                                
999999999147483649
```

Without overflow.

I don't understand `l` mean `long int` and `ll` mean `long long int` so why they aren't any difference?

Comment: What is the difference between a `long int` and a `long long int` on your platform?

Comment: I'm using this online compiler to perform my tests : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: A helpful addition to your program would be:  `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(long), sizeof(long long));`  If they are the same, that's why the output is as it is.

Comment: @eddiem Right, thank's i'm now understanding why it's produce the same output :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some computers, `long` and `long long` have the same representation, so `ll` and `l` do the same thing.  This is true for most 64-bit platforms, except Windows.  (This is an explanation of why it worked that way, not a promise that it must work that way.)

On other platforms—64-bit Windows, 32-bit anything, you will not be so lucky.

The program is incorrect either way, it just *happened* to work by chance, and there is no guarantee that it will continue to work, even on the same platform.

Answer (score 1):

"%ld" is not guaranteed to handle 64-bit integers.
"%lld" is.

In many implementations of the C library, there is no difference, but some platforms might not print large 64-bit numbers with %ld